# Research Study Seeks First Time Parents

Tags: discussion, survey

First-time parent?

Researchers at Davidson College are studying new parents’ relationships with their partners and babies. You may be eligible to participate if:

You have a baby under six months of age

Are between the ages of 18 and 45

Are currently in a relationship

Live in the United States

Participation involves completing a series of surveys online. 
Completion of these measures is anticipated to take 30 minutes or less.

Participants who complete the study may enter a raffle for a $100 gift card to Amazon or a similar vendor.

Interested in participating? To learn more about the study, visit the link below (Note: link may not redirect from this page; if there is an issue, please copy and paste the address into your search bar).

[https://davidsonedu.co1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_eL4O3csNSbSgwzr](https://davidsonedu.co1.qualtrics.com/%E2%80%A6/%E2%80%A6/SV_eL4O3csNSbSgwzr)

If you have any questions or would like to learn more about the study, please contact the researcher or faculty sponsor:

Kathleen Little

kalittle@davidson.edu

Faculty Sponsor: Laura E. Sockol, Ph.D.

Assistant Professor of Psychology

Davidson College

Davidson, NC 28035

lasockol@davidson.edu

(704) 894-2288

Comment: Hi, Katie! I'm afraid these aren't allowed on Stack Exchange. Please see the information in this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74738/recruiting-participants-on-stack-overflow-for-an-empirical-study

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question seeking an answer.

Comment: Asking for research participants is allowed on meta. I am migrating your post.

Comment: FYI: Your link doesn't work. 403 Forbidden.

Comment: I have fixed the link so it should be in working order! Thank you for alerting me that it was faulty.